# Read Call Log on Mono for Android

Tags: c#, android, mono, monodevelop, xamarin.android

I found many answers about reading the call log on Android, but I am looking to do the same using Mono for Android.

Mono for Android is using C#, I am tired of searching over and over again without finding any answer.

Comment: Mono for Android has the ~exact same API as Java for Android, so your best bet is probably to port one of the samples you found.

Comment: Class names are different, you cant just use the same code sample and simply change the syntax, I may need to go through the entire documentation to find out what are the classes to use, I was hoping to find some code samples

Comment: The class names should be the same in 99% of the cases.

Answer (score 1):

```
// filter call logs by type = missed
string queryFilter = String.Format ("{0}={1}", CallLog.Calls.Type, (int)CallType.Missed);

// filter in desc order limit by 3
string querySorter = String.Format ("{0} desc limit 3", CallLog.Calls.Date);

// CallLog.Calls.ContentUri is the path where data is saved
Android.Database.ICursor queryData = ContentResolver.Query (CallLog.Calls.ContentUri, null, queryFilter, null, querySorter);

while(queryData.MoveToNext())
{
   String dialNumber = queryData.GetString     (queryData.GetColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.Number));

  // do your stuffs, get more data, whatever...
}
```

found [here](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/4933/call-log)